# Is there a script to stamp & password protect a PDF on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-script, pdf

I have a few PDFs on a Google Drive, I would like to watermark/stamp & password protect (to disallow editing) before I share them.

Is there a solution using Google App Scripts?

Answer (score -1):

There is no solution using Apps Script to watermark/stamp and password protect a PDF on Google Drive.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?